# Unfamiliar operator in C# += and EventHandlers

Tags: c#, event-handling

What does the += operator do? It's difficult to find information on this operator online, though it seems to suggest that it has something to do with delegates. Can someone explain a bit more?

Anyway this below is the c# statement that i came across:

`this.LineSelected += new LineSelectionHandler(AdvancedReceiptViewModel_LineSelected);`

Comment: So you know it's an operator, so why not start by searching for [C# operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) - first result will point you to [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx): `The += operator is also used to specify a method that will be called in response to an event; such methods are called event handlers. The use of the += operator in this context is referred to as subscribing to an event. `

Comment: You may not be familiar with VB.NET but, in case you are, it is equivalent to an `AddHandler` statement.

Answer (score 2):

it adds an EventHandler to that event.

for example:

```
Button.Click += new EventHandler(my_handler)
```

`Click` is an Event which you wish to handle or listen to and `my_handler` is a method that will be called when that event occurs.

Answer (score 1):

For EventHandlers the `+=` has a semantic of subscribe or `-=` unsubscribe https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`+=` is additional operator. that means right side component integrated with leftside component. `x+=y` - `x=x+y` `button.Click += new event()` - click event process enable for button.